# uWSGI in an environment with Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, virtualenv, uwsgi

**Answer:** https://bradenmacdonald.com/blog/2015/uwsgi-emperor-multiple-python

**Original Post:**

I started with python2 and uwsgi. Got my Django app running. I installed python3 and now I'm trying to get my app to run using python3.

However it seems uwsgi doesn't want to run using python3 - even if passing it the venv flag for my virtualenv with python3. I have an emperor running a few vassals, if I include the venv flag said vassal doesn't work.

On a test server, I simply removed python2, then aliased /usr/bin/python to python3. Which fixed the issue. But this seems like the wrong solution and would result in more significant downtime on my application.

Whats the best way to get uWSGI to work with python3 without deleting python3? Is it really to create an alias?

**Update 1**:
Installing pip3 `apt install pip3` on the server and installing uwsgi using `pip3 install uwsgi` is now getting uwsgi running in python3. However I don't understand this behavior. I'm getting an unrelated error now regarding `ImportError: No module named 'encodings'`

**Update 2**: uwsgi is using 3.5 now - while my viortualenv is using python3.6. I created an environment with python3.5 which worked.

How do I make uwsgi build for python3.6? Since the above is a brute force approach.

Comment: Is uWSGI giving you any error messages, tracebacks, etc?

Comment: @Wyatt yes. Heres the most recent given the progress mase.
`Python version: 3.5.2 (default, Sep 14 2017, 22:51:06)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]`
`Set PythonHome to /opt/mysite/venvs/p36`
`Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding`
`ImportError: No module named 'encodings'`

`Current thread 0x00007f22164ea700 (most recent call first):`
`Aborted (core dumped)`

Comment: Can you `apt install uwsgi` instead of installing it via `pip`?

Comment: Also, did you revert `/usr/bin/python` back to what it was originally?

Comment: @Wyatt /usb/bin/python is normal, the aliasing was on a test server. So I got it working now. it seems that both the uwsgi python version had to match the python version in virtualenv. Ill update main question

Answer (score 1):

Add
**--plugin python3**
in the running command and install uwsgi python3 plugin using
**apt install uwsgi-plugin-python3**